# Camel Routing Config File with Query Params

Tags: apache-camel, query-string

I have a '.route' file for a rest service that works, it has the resource in the middle of the URI:

```
<from uri='restlet:/foo/{id}/bar
```

This works just fine, I am able to retrieve the 'id' in code using:

```
String id = e.getIn().getHeader("id", String.class);
```

Now, I want a '.route' with a URI with a query parameter in it.
I tried a bunch of ways, like:

```
<from uri='restlet:/foo/baz?color={aColor}
```

But this does not work, I get a 404 error, the server cannot find the URI.
This seems to be a very easy/general thing, anybody know how to do this?
I looked over the docs, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

All params follow after the question mark receive as the camel options(for example restletMethod, connectionTimeout.... see http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html). Just use `<from uri='restlet:/foo/{id}/bar` in your route, pass the parameters in query like a `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/rs/foo/1234/bar?color=red` and get it `String id = e.getIn().getHeader("color", String.class);`